# Cargar programa antes que Windows Shell

Tags: registro-windows

Buenas, me presento aquí por primera vez, a ver si puedo solucionar un problema que tengo.

Trabajo en un ciber de videojuegos, trabajo con SmartLaunch, una capa de bloqueo que cierra explorer.exe, restringe el uso del PC... lo típico.

El problema es que carga el escritorio antes que el SmartLaunch, durante un tiempo el PC es accesible y da tiempo a ejecutar cualquier cosa. Una vez carga SmartLaunch queda el PC bloqueado de nuevo, pero lo que haya sido ejecutado queda abierto.

Lo que yo quiero hacer es cargar SmartLaunch antes que "explorer.exe".

He probado editando el registro de windows:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]

Cambiando el valor de "Shell" para que apunte al ejecutable de SmartLaunch. Pero no me carga, no carga el explorador de windows, pero tampoco me carga el programa. Tampoco funciona editandolo de USER en lugar de MACHINE, o modificando el valor de "userinit" para que apunte a dicho programa.

Si que he conseguido cargar otras shells con este método para descartar algún error (bblean), así que no sé por qué no me carga este programa. Ovio que algo se me escapa, pero no sé qué.

También he probado a instalar el programa como servicio, cosa que ha sido inútil.

Me faltan muchas cosas por aprender y esto me tiene pillado ¿qué se me escapa?

Un saludo, y gracias de antemano.

Comment: usen este programa en youtube dice como usarlo se llama TSheller 1.7

Answer (score 0):

En esa ruta del registro, en `UserInit` deberás poner la ruta de `SmartLaunch` antes de la de `userinit.exe` sin borrar esta segunda. Mas o menos de la siguiente manera:

> C:...\smartlaunch.exe,C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe

Comment: No funciona tampoco, me sigue pasando lo mismo. Me carga el escritorio y después carga el programa como hacía anteriormente.

Estoy pensando otras soluciones, que además me arreglarían varios problemas que tengo con las teclas multimedia del teclado y que solo funcionan con explorer.exe corriendo.
Lo que quiero hacer es eliminar la barra de tareas, no por programa externo, si no por registro de windows o método similar ¿es eso posible? me ha parecido ver que lo es en Win7 y XP, pero no encuentro el modo de eliminarla en Win10, y TaskBar eliminator no consigue lo que deseo.